# Anonymous class accessing local variable in java

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I saw this piece of code and it's not making sense to me. array arr[] is passed as argument to `intArrayAsList` method, then it is used by methods get and size. But nowhere reference to arr is passed via constructor or setter, so how are these methods able to access arr, because arr is not a property of the object created by anonymous class.

```java
static List<Integer> intArrayAsList(int arr[])
{
    return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return arr[index];
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return arr.length;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: That’s just how nested/anonymous classes work in Java. They inherit the surrounding scope (with some restrictions).

Comment: Does it work like closures in javascript

Comment: @BHAVUKGARG: the effect is very similar, yes.